# Get the most popular product in the same category

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have 2 tables in my Postgres database.

First table 'products': https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ZMI.jpg

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists PRODUCTS (product_id varchar PRIMARY KEY, product_name varchar, price int, gender varchar,
category varchar, sub_category varchar, sub_sub_category varchar);
```

And my second table 'pop_products': https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TF5l.jpg
This contains the product id's and the the number of times they've been sold.
Note: the 'product_id' in 'pop_products' is not a foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists POP_PRODUCTS (product_id varchar PRIMARY KEY, freq int);
```

My goal is to find the most popular product with the same category.

My code up until now:

```
SELECT product_id FROM products 
HERE category LIKE '""" + category[0] + """'
AND product_id NOT LIKE CAST(""" + productid + """ AS varchar)
```

I've been sitting here scratching my head for the last 30 minutes, trying to figure out a solution but no bueno till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you can use `distinct on` after joining the tables together:

```
select distinct on (p.category) p.*, pp.freq
from pop_products pp join
     products p
     using (product_id)
order by p.category, pp.freq desc;
```